# Determine whether a routine has gcc's tail call optimisation applied to it

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization, tail-recursion

I need to determine whether a set of routines in a shared object have gcc's tail-call optimization applied to it.
Need a C code, preferably using APIs instead of 'nm' or 'objdump' system commands.

Any links for more info will be helpful

Details:
For eg. the original C code is like

```
void myFunc1(){
   ... // Do something
   myFunc2();
   return;
}
```

Dump of assembler code for function myFunc1:

```
   0x57ad50b0 <+0>:     push   %ebp
   0x57ad50b1 <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x57ad50b3 <+3>:     mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x57ad50b6 <+6>:     pop    %ebp
   0x57ad50b7 <+7>:     lea    0x8(%eax),%edx
   0x57ad50ba <+10>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x57ad50bc <+12>:    jmp    0x57ab8010 <myFunc2>
```

As we can see the last instruction is not "call myFunc2" but simply "jmp myFunc2".
Due to this we cannot obtain the information about "myFunc1" from the stack trace.
So we need to determine beforehand that "myFunc1" can have this issue, so that we can resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to use compiler dumps

```
int bar (int x);

int
foo (int x)
{
  return bar(x);
}
```

Compile with:

```
gcc -O2 -S tailcall.c -fdump-tree-tailc-lineno-details
```

In the dump file tailcall.c.137t.tailc, you will see:

```
;; Function foo (foo, funcdef_no=0, decl_uid=1721, cgraph_uid=0)

Found tail call [tailcall.c : 6:3] _4 = bar (x_2(D)); [tail call]
```

Next you may analyze this way all your project. GCC will write all places where tail calls are found.

But this way is gcc version-dependent. My output is valid for gcc 4.8.x, but for other branches, number of tailcall tree pass, its name or dump format may differ.

Also if tail calls is issue for you, then just use -fno-optimize-sibling-calls option

```
gcc -O2 -S tailcall.c -fno-optimize-sibling-calls
```

will produce output without sibling calls at all.

Comment: This is a very useful information. 
But is there a way to determine it directly from the shared object, without recompiling the code. 
Also we cannot disable this optimisation as this is not our code. Our program only has access to the stack trace of the main program and can analyze the shared objects for this optimisation.

Comment: If it was compiled without DWARF debug information, then I don't believe, it is possible.

Comment: I think some debug info is available like routine name and its size. Is there some deterministic way to find out whether tail-call is applied by going through the disassemble of code. I am thinking of looking for the prescence of jmp instruction at the end of routine instead of call/ret.